# Cannot show/hide canvas using button Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

In my project, I have a canvas `<div>` where I can write/draw with the mouse. 
It was working fine, so I added a simple button that shows and hides this `div` every time you click on it, but when I do that, it does not catch the mouse events, I can't draw/write, the canvas dimensions are not equal to what I set in attributes.

I've tried multiple things all day but I can't figure it out.

Here is what I've added to HTML :

```
<button type="button" (click)="Draw()" id="bt">{{des}}</button>
<div *ngIf="show">
  <div class="canvas">
    <canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Erase" (click)="Erase()"/>
</div>
```

All I did was surround my canvas with a `div`.

Comment: What did you put in your @Component ?

Comment: I attempted to make your title more descriptive.  If it doesn't accurately summarize the issue, please edit it accordingly.

Comment: I have some methods in my component : draw() getcanvas() captureevents  using htmlcanvaselement.

Comment: it was working good but after i aded the hide/show method and call it in html the canvas won't show correctly and won't let me draw on it

Comment: Yes i use Angular, no i don't use hostlistener.

Comment: Check the error log; replace ngif with [hidden]="!show" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still can use [hidden] with the reverse logic:

```
<div [hidden]="!show">
  ...
</div>
```